# How do I get the "Netpay" to subtract the "Federal and State Tax" from the gross pay? (The Federal and State Tax" is supposed to be 15%)

Tags: java, eclipse

Need this to be 15%

```
public double calculatePay( int hours, double HourlyWage )
{
    double Federal_and_State_Tax = (0.15);
```

Standard working hours = 40

```
    if ( hours > STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS ) 
    { 
        int Overtime = (hours - STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS);
        GrossPay = ( STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS * HourlyWage ) + ( Overtime * HourlyWage) * 1.5;
```

Need to statement to say: (Hours over 40 * hourlywage * 150%) - 15%

```
        NetPay = ( STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS * HourlyWage ) + ( Overtime * HourlyWage * 1.5) - Federal_and_State_Tax;
    }
    else GrossPay = hours * HourlyWage;
         NetPay = (hours * HourlyWage) - Federal_and_State_Tax;
  

    return GrossPay;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure I understand your question, but I think you want to do something like

```java
public double calculatePay( int hours, double HourlyWage )
{
    double NetPay = hours * HourlyWage
    if ( hours > STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS ) 
    { 
        int Overtime = (hours - STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS);
        NetPay = NetPay + ( Overtime * HourlyWage * 0.5);
    }
    double GrossPay = NetPay * (1-Federal_and_State_Tax);
    return GrossPay;
}
```